# If $\int f\;d\mu=\int g\;d\mu$, then $f\equiv g$ almost everywhere

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, probability-theory

I'm wondering whether or not the following statement is true: Let

- $(\Omega,\mathcal{A},\mu)$ be a measure space
- $f,g:\Omega\to\overline{\mathbb{R}}$ be measurable with respect to $\mathcal{A}$ and $$\int f\;d\mu=\int g\;d\mu$$
  Then, $$f\equiv g\;\;\;\text{almost everywhere}$$

Let $h:=f-g$. I know that if $h\ge 0$ almost everywhere, then $h\equiv 0$ almost everywhere iff $\int h\;d\mu=0$. But what can we say in the general case?

Comment: I don't see how $\mathcal X$ is relevant here. What makes you doubt this is true?

Comment: @tomasz You're right. I've completely updated my quesiton.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not true. For example,
$$\int_0^{2\pi}\sin x\,dx=0=\int_0^{2\pi}\cos x\,dx.$$
However, if $f$ and $g$ are integrable and
$$\int_Ef\,d\mu=\int_Eg\,d\mu$$
for every measurable set $E$, then yes, $f=g$ almost everywhere.

Comment: For your second comment, you will need some other condition on the measure space to say that $f=g$ a.e. Consider $f=1$, $g=2$ and $\mu(E)=\infty$ if $E$ is not the empty set.

Comment: @DPoole We only need that $f$ and $g$ are integrable, but yes I forgot to specify that (see Rudin Real and Complex Analysis Theorem 1.39 (b)). Thank you, I just edited the answer.